# Either always hide, or always show the scrollbar in mobile version of Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have an issue on my site where fixed background images (to get parallax effects) images are being shifted in size as the scrollbar in mobile browsers appears and disappears. I have tried the following to either always force, or always hide the scrollbar (Either would be a solution, I don't mind) however none seem to work:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    html {
        margin-left: calc(100vw - 100%);
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Solution 2:

```
body { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Was the ability to change how the scroll bar behaves and looks in android browsers removed? As I also notice my altered scrollbar doesn't appear in the app, yet does in mobile dev view.

Comment: Why did you undo my edit? Your code is not formatted well and titles are easier to read in sentence case.Questions on StackOverflow should be edited to make them better for other users, and edits gets reviewed by 2 higher level users to approve if it makes it better or not. My edit was approved because it was helpful. I will fix it again for you :)

Comment: Hi, I appreciated the edit but there was a typo in the title, that was all.

Comment: You are able to edit it again afterwards if you want to :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realise :)